# Converting lat-long to PostGIS geometry without querying the database

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgis

I have a table in postgresql with a PostGIS geometry(point, 4326) column (location, using SRID 4326) and I have a Python application that using SQL Alchemy updates the table (the rest of the columns) without any problem.

Now, I need to update the location column and I know I can use the proper text representation of a given location to update the column using SQL Alchemy without the need to use GEOAlchemy, for instance I can update the column with the value: '0101000020E6100000AEAC7EB61F835DC0241CC418A2F74040'

which corresponds to lat:33.9346343 long:-118.0488106

The question is: is there a way to compute in Python this '0101000020E6100000AEAC7EB61F835DC0241CC418A2F74040' having this (33.9346343 ,-118.0488106) as an input without querying the database? or any way to update the column using a proper text input?

I know I can use SQLAlchemy to execute this query:

```
select st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-118.0488106, 33.9346343),4326)
```

and obtain the value to update the column, but I want to avoid that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not `UPDATE your_table SET your_field = st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-118.0488106, 33.9346343),4326) WHERE your_filter` ?

Comment: Because I'm using an ORM layer that doesn't allow me to run that kind of update, instead I can pass over an object to store it in the database, and at this point I should have (in python) the value of the column.

Comment: PostGIS is open source. You can just download the source code, search it for that function and rewrite it to python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution to this problem is rather easier than it seems. To update the field using text and the input lat-long all I needed to do was defining the SRID in the text assign:

location = 'SRID=4326;POINT(-118.0488106 33.9346343)'

This will update the geometry(point,4326) column properly and when you do a select in the table the value of the column is the expected one:

"0101000020E6100000AEAC7EB61F835DC0241CC418A2F74040"

Thanks guys!

Comment: another way that I saw being generated from a plugin called knex-postgis is to do location = 'ST_geomFromText(\'Point(-118.0488106 33.9346343)\', <SRID number>)' but if you do this manually just be careful of escaping the string